# Nested ul moving parent ul to depth of child li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to figure out how to get my parent or `<ul class="main-ul">` to stay stationary. I realize it is something to do with my positioning or at least I think, but I am not sure what it is or why. Currently when child `<ul>` is expanded under each item the entire parent `<li>` follows.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.main-ul').children('li').on('click', function() {
     $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('slow');
   });
});
```

```css
.home-main-nav-menu {
  border-style: double;
  border-color: cyan;
}
.main-li-items {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-style: double;
  border-color: purple;
}
.sub-li-items {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: -40.5px;
  border-style: double;
  border-color: yellow;
}
.main-li-items > ul {
  display: none;
}
.main-ul {
  border-style: double;
  border-color: green;
  margin-left: -3px
}
ul {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<nav class = "home-main-nav-menu">
  <ul class="main-ul">
    <li class="main-li-items"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
      <li class="main-li-items"><a href="#/">About Me</a>
        <ul>
          <li class="sub-li-items"><a href="#/">Education</a></li>
          <li class="sub-li-items"><a href="#/">Lessons</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="main-li-items"><a href="#/">Blog</a></li>
      <li class="main-li-items"><a href="#/">Contact</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="sub-li-items"><a href="#/">Email</a></li>
        <li class="sub-li-items"><a href="#/">Phone</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
      <li class="main-li-items"><a href="#/">Portfolio</a>
      <ul>
        <li class ="sub-li-items"><a href="#/">Recent</a></li>
        <li class="sub-li-items"><a href="#/">All</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li class = "main-li-items"><a href="#/">Collaborate</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="sub-li-items"><a href="#/">Now</a></li>
        <li class="sub-li-items"><a href="#/">Later</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Are you wanting the green bounding border to expand, but for the remaining links to stay at the top when a dropdown is shown?

Comment: Yes, that would work, unless thats an poor way of accomplishing this task. I just would like the main ul items or parent ul items to stay at the top like a normal drop down

Answer (score 0):

If you add `vertical-align: top` to your `main-li-items` the drop will be down, and not up.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.main-ul').children('li').on('click', function() {
     $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('slow');
   });
});
```

```css
.home-main-nav-menu {
  border-style: double;
  border-color: cyan;
}
.main-li-items {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-style: double;
  border-color: purple;
}
.sub-li-items {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: -40.5px;
  border-style: double;
  border-color: yellow;
}
.main-li-items > ul {
  display: none;
}
.main-ul {
  border-style: double;
  border-color: green;
  margin-left: -3px
}
ul {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<nav class = "home-main-nav-menu">
  <ul class="main-ul">
    <li class="main-li-items"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
      <li class="main-li-items"><a href="#/">About Me</a>
        <ul>
          <li class="sub-li-items"><a href="#/">Education</a></li>
          <li class="sub-li-items"><a href="#/">Lessons</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="main-li-items"><a href="#/">Blog</a></li>
      <li class="main-li-items"><a href="#/">Contact</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="sub-li-items"><a href="#/">Email</a></li>
        <li class="sub-li-items"><a href="#/">Phone</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
      <li class="main-li-items"><a href="#/">Portfolio</a>
      <ul>
        <li class ="sub-li-items"><a href="#/">Recent</a></li>
        <li class="sub-li-items"><a href="#/">All</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li class = "main-li-items"><a href="#/">Collaborate</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="sub-li-items"><a href="#/">Now</a></li>
        <li class="sub-li-items"><a href="#/">Later</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can position the sub-menu `absolute` so that it stays out of the flow.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.main-ul').children('li').on('click', function() {
     $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('slow');
   });
});
```

```css
.home-main-nav-menu{
  border-style: double;
  border-color: cyan;
}
.main-li-items{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-style: double;
  border-color: purple;
}
.sub-li-items{
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: -40.5px;
  border-style: double;
  border-color: yellow;
}
.main-li-items > ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
.main-ul{
  border-style: double;
  border-color: green;
  margin-left: -3px
}
ul{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
  <nav class = "home-main-nav-menu">
    <ul class = "main-ul">
      <li class = "main-li-items"><a href = "#/">Home</a></li>
      <li class = "main-li-items"><a href = "#/">About Me</a>
        <ul>
          <li class = "sub-li-items"><a href = "#/">Education</a></li>
          <li class = "sub-li-items"><a href = "#/">Lessons</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class = "main-li-items"><a href = "#/">Blog</a></li>
      <li class = "main-li-items"><a href = "#/">Contact</a>
      <ul>
        <li class = "sub-li-items"><a href = "#/">Email</a></li>
        <li class = "sub-li-items"><a href = "#/">Phone</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
      <li class = "main-li-items"><a href = "#/">Portfolio</a>
      <ul>
        <li class = "sub-li-items"><a href = "#/">Recent</a></li>
        <li class = "sub-li-items"><a href = "#/">All</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
      <li class = "main-li-items"><a href = "#/">Collaborate</a>
      <ul>
        <li class = "sub-li-items"><a href = "#/">Now</a></li>
        <li class = "sub-li-items"><a href = "#/">Later</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: This is perfect. Would you mind giving a brief explantion to what exactly stays absolute? is it all parent items above the child? Is it just the direct parent? I'm having a hard time grasping this concept, more trouble than I did with oop haha

Comment: With `position: absolute;`, an element is positioned based it's parent element, and goes out of the regular flow of the page.

Comment: I applied `position: absolute;` to the `ul` of the sub-menu, so that it doesn't effect it's parent element.  You can use `top`, `bottom`, `right` and `left` to tweak it's position.  But the key is - it doesn't affect the position of other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

Only change:

```
.main-li-items {
  ...
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.main-ul').children('li').on('click', function() {
     $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('slow');
   });
});
```

```css
.home-main-nav-menu {
  border-style: double;
  border-color: cyan;
}
.main-li-items {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-style: double;
  border-color: purple;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.sub-li-items {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: -40.5px;
  border-style: double;
  border-color: yellow;
}
.main-li-items > ul {
  display: none;
}
.main-ul {
  border-style: double;
  border-color: green;
  margin-left: -3px
}
ul {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<nav class = "home-main-nav-menu">
  <ul class="main-ul">
    <li class="main-li-items"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
      <li class="main-li-items"><a href="#/">About Me</a>
        <ul>
          <li class="sub-li-items"><a href="#/">Education</a></li>
          <li class="sub-li-items"><a href="#/">Lessons</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="main-li-items"><a href="#/">Blog</a></li>
      <li class="main-li-items"><a href="#/">Contact</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="sub-li-items"><a href="#/">Email</a></li>
        <li class="sub-li-items"><a href="#/">Phone</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
      <li class="main-li-items"><a href="#/">Portfolio</a>
      <ul>
        <li class ="sub-li-items"><a href="#/">Recent</a></li>
        <li class="sub-li-items"><a href="#/">All</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li class = "main-li-items"><a href="#/">Collaborate</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="sub-li-items"><a href="#/">Now</a></li>
        <li class="sub-li-items"><a href="#/">Later</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```